# Why El Capitan update makes my fonts italic?

Tags: fonts, osx-elcapitan

I update my mac to El Capitan but I have very interesting problem. If open sans font-weight is more than 400 or less than 400 font shows normal. But, if open sans normal weight, fonts show italic. Even in google fonts page;
[image]

I check my friend's mac and everything normal in there. How can I solve that?